# Pressure that a pipe can withstand

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

The wall of a pipe of diameter 60 cm is constructed of a sheet of mild steel of thickness 0.3 cm. The pipe is filled with water under high pressure.
What is the maximum pressure, that is, force per unit area, that the pipe can withstand?

I know that the Bulk modulus for mild steel is:

$$B_s = 16\times10^{10}$$
the equation for bulk modulus is:
$$\frac{\Delta V}{V} = \frac{1}{B} \frac{F}{A} $$

I was trying to solve for the pressure $\frac fa$ but I don't have the change in volume the clue I am seeing is the thickness of the pipe is there any equation I can use to solve for the pressure?

notice the ultimate strenght of the steel is :

$$U_s = 3.8 \times 10^8$$

Comment: Use https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/stress-thin-walled-tube-d_948.html

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu using that equations I get 3.8*10^6 an the answer is 3.8*10^5

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeualso would like to see the derivation of such equations

Comment: I believe there is error in input data or answer. About derivation: I didn't find it, but I believe it is something about solving Laplace equation in thin wall cylinder.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu already solve it But I have to multiplt by 0.20 instead of 2 why is that?

Comment: The only possible reason I can suppose is safety factor, but 10 is too much